# excluded files are not being skipped

Tags: javascript, node.js, ava

so I have the following `files` setup

```
"files" : [
    "testing/tests/**",
    "!testing/tests/**/__helpers__/*",
],
```

However, files in the `__helpers__` folder are not being skipped

```
  ✖ No tests found in testing/tests/graphql/stage-2/__helpers__/workspace/setup.ts, make sure to import "ava" at the top of your test file
  - graphql › stage-2 › tests › workspace.ts › do later
  ✔ general › tests › functions.ts › functions returns proper difference
  ─

  `--fail-fast` is on. 1 test file was skipped.

  1 test passed
  1 test todo
```

What's wrong with my setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding `"!testing/tests/**/__helpers__/*"` would ignore all the files in `__helpers__`, however in the provided error, `setup.ts` is within another directory. Try changing it to:

```
"files" : [
    "testing/tests/**",
    "!testing/tests/**/__helpers__/*/**",
]
```